# Jenkins git pull using ssh failing with github

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, ssh-keys

I know I can use a `GitHub Plugin` with the `Jenkins Server`, but I'm simply trying to use `Git` with any Git Repo in the `pipeline` script.
In the `Jenkins`, I'm getting the files from a github project using ssh. The `ssh public key` is already added to **github settings** and the `Jenkins Credential Manager` has the `ssh private key` as ***SSH Username with private key*** without the `user name`.

The `pipeline` using this credential, cloning the repo without any issue:
[image]

and I can access and list the files in the location using the `pipeline script`:

```
     stage('Test') {
            steps {
                dir ("$WORKSPACE") {
                   bat 'dir'
                   echo 'We are in ' + pwd()

                    bat '''
                        git status
                        git checkout main
                        git pull -f -p
                        git status
                    '''                    

                }
                
            }
        }
```

However, the `git pull -f -p` is failing with the following error ***(Although, not failing the build)***:

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read
> from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

#### Here is the log part.

```bash
[Pipeline] pwd
[Pipeline] echo
We are in D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test
[Pipeline] bat

D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test>git status 
HEAD detached at 65d3be6
nothing to commit, working tree clean

D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test>git checkout main 
Your branch is behind 'origin/main' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
Previous HEAD position was 65d3be6 Update Jenkinsfile
Switched to branch 'main'

D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test>git pull -f -p 
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test>git status 
On branch main
Your branch is behind 'origin/main' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
[Pipeline] }
```

#### But working out of Jenkins on the node:

However, if I directly go to the same folder on the Node (Apparently, it is the only node and on my own machine), and issue the same `git` commands, it works without any errors.

```bash
D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test :: git(1e83d3d)> git status
HEAD detached at 1e83d3d
nothing to commit, working tree clean

D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test :: git(1e83d3d)> git pull
You are not currently on a branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test :: git(1e83d3d)> git checkout main
Switched to a new branch 'main'
branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'.

D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test :: git(main)> git pull -f
Updating cd899c6..72aafe2
Fast-forward
 Jenkinsfile | 13 +++++++------
 1 file changed, 7 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)

D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test :: git(main)> git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test :: git(main)>git pull -f -p
Already up to date.
```

#### Here is the full log if required by anyone:

```bash
Started by user Farrukh Waheed
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git git@github.com:Farrukhw/ansible.learn.git
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 913e5d57-48cc-4309-90aa-0854ed98de32
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test\.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@github.com:Farrukhw/ansible.learn.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:Farrukhw/ansible.learn.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.41.0.windows.1'
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
Verifying host key using manually-configured host key entries
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@github.com:Farrukhw/ansible.learn.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 65d3be618ce9b1b36da6d49d66410758b10e67ce (refs/remotes/origin/main)
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 65d3be618ce9b1b36da6d49d66410758b10e67ce # timeout=10
Commit message: "Update Jenkinsfile"
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list --no-walk 72aafe2f6a9d25504ddcb878537941a69afd6345 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] pwd
[Pipeline] echo
We are in D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test
[Pipeline] echo
Current workspace is D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test
[Pipeline] echo
Current workspace is D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] echo
Testing..
[Pipeline] dir
Running in D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] bat

D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test>dir
 Volume in drive D is Disk1.Part2
 Volume Serial Number is 94CE-288F

 Directory of D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test

20/07/2023  04:27 pm    <DIR>          .
19/07/2023  11:53 pm    <DIR>          ..
19/07/2023  11:53 pm               584 conditional.yml
19/07/2023  11:53 pm               231 docker-compose.yaml
19/07/2023  11:53 pm               962 Dockerfile
20/07/2023  04:18 pm               124 file1.txt
19/07/2023  11:53 pm                16 file2.txt
20/07/2023  04:27 pm             1,137 Jenkinsfile
19/07/2023  11:53 pm               946 looping.yml
19/07/2023  11:53 pm             1,333 MyInventoryFile.ini
19/07/2023  11:53 pm               721 MyPlayBook.yml
19/07/2023  11:53 pm               666 README.md
              10 File(s)          6,720 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  440,398,180,352 bytes free
[Pipeline] pwd
[Pipeline] echo
We are in D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test
[Pipeline] bat

D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test>git status 
HEAD detached at 65d3be6
nothing to commit, working tree clean

D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test>git checkout main 
Your branch is behind 'origin/main' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
Previous HEAD position was 65d3be6 Update Jenkinsfile
Switched to branch 'main'

D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test>git pull -f -p 
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test>git status 
On branch main
Your branch is behind 'origin/main' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
[Pipeline] echo
Deploying....
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test@tmp\jfrog\19\.jfrog deleted
Finished: SUCCESS
```

### Question:

Jenkins Node is the same machine where `ssh keys` are working with the `github` repo from the command line. Why **Jenkins** is giving the following error with `git pull` command, even when it was able to clone it using the credentials with the `ssh-private key` against the `ssh-public key` already added to `github`??

```bash
D:\Jenkins\Home\workspace\git.ssh.test>git pull -f -p 
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Two things here: first, you configure the credentials in pipeline settings — the credentials (saved inside Jenkins) allow it to successfully pull. Second, you start a `bat` process which doesn't have access to Jenkins credentials — this is why it fails. You may want to wrap your `bat` call inside `sshagent (credentials: ['DESKTOP-2OH'])`.